# Casting void* to other types

Tags: c, casting

I'm getting the error:

```
error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type
```

For the following code:

```
Button config_b1 = Button("b1");
Button config_b2 = Button("b2");
Button config_b3 = Button("b3");

const void *const buttons[3] PROGMEM = {
&config_b1, &config_b2, &config_b3
};
```

in some function:

```
(Button)*buttons[1]->setText("Foo");
```

The casting to Button fails.

This is just a simplified example. The array "buttons" will have different types of objects, so I need to initialize it as void and then cast to the proper type inside the function.

Comment: `Button config_b1 = Button("b1");` That looks like C++. Also, you cannot dereference a `void*` because `void` is an incomplete type.

Comment: It looks like OO-style programming using C, of the kind you often see when C++ is not available.

Comment: @TobySpeight Then how can they use the type name `Button` as a function too? In C++ this is valid, as it will construct a `Button` object. I can't think of a way this is valid C (besides macro hell).

Comment: @TobySpeight C wouldn't allow you to give the type and the constructor the same name. Also, OO in C most often uses incomplete type, meaning pointers and not directly allocated instances.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ allows you to cast from `const type* const` to `type*`. This is an invalid pointer conversion. Using `void*` like this is not a good idea in either language.

Comment: You may be right about the naming - I read it as pseudo-code, absent a [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a simple precedence error, and you need

```
((Button *) buttons[1])->setText("foo");
```

Are you sure this is C, by the way? That kind of call really looks like C++ (it could be C, but then you'd need an explicit `this` equivalent in most cases).

Comment: I am looking at it as a simple C function pointer, but not sure what you mean by _`this` equivalent_.  Can you comment please?

Comment: Thanks buddy, it worked fine! By the way, this code is a mix of C and C++ code. Cheers.